# Fredholm type Toeplitz characterization

Tags: operator-theory

Let $A$ denote the *-algebra generated by all Toeplitz operators $T_ϕ$ with symbol $ϕ \in C(\mathbb{T})$. I'm concerned with the argument for the implication:

$T_ϕ$ is Fredholm then $T_ϕ+K(H^2)$ is invertible in $A(H^2)/K(H^2)$. The in between step involving Atkinson's I'm well familiar with.

Comment: Ref: http://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~richard/teaching/f2015/Inoue.pdf

Comment: $B(H^2)/K(H^2)$ is a unital C* -algebra, and $A(H^2)/K(H^2) \subset B(H^2)/K(H^2)$ is a C*-subalgebra containing the unit. So $\sigma_{B(H^2)/K(H^2)}(T_ϕ+K(H^2)) = \sigma_{A(H^2)/K(H^2)}(T_ϕ+K(H^2))$. Therefore the implication.